# Getting next value from sequence sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the next value from this filed `SU - 1 /2016`

Query I used

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(InvoiceNO,4, 1)), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
from [dbo].[Invoice]
```

The query output is `0001`, it should be `0002`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You substring this value `SU - 1 /2016` from 4th position which gives you "-". So to get the 1 you need to start from 6th position which gives you expected output.

```
SELECT 
RIGHT('000' + CAST(ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(InvoiceNO,6, 1)), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) 
from [dbo].[Invoice]
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this code.**

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST((ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(exampleColumn,6, 1)), 0) + 1) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
from [dbo].tblExample
```

You have take a char from 4th position but your data "1" is at 6th position.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you are using the `substring` function on `SU - 1 /2016`. You take a substring from 4th position with a length of 1 (remember `substring` is 1 based, not 0). So you are getting `-`. If you try:

```
SELECT '-' + 1
```

Gives: `1`.
You'll probably need to start 'substringing' at position 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your script a bit shorter and use this instead:

```
SELECT RIGHT(MAX(SUBSTRING(InvoiceNO,6, 1)) + 10001, 4)
-- Including this for test:
FROM (values('SU - 1 /2016')) x(InvoiceNO)
```

Comment: SELECT RIGHT(MAX(SUBSTRING(InvoiceNO,6, 1)) + 10001, 4)
-- Including this for test:
FROM (values('SU - 0002 /2016')) x(InvoiceNO) given different out put

Comment: @MukeshKalgude I tried, I am getting the same output as the other answers. Can you be more specific ?